# UI Fabric TextField in spfx for SP2019 - overwrite css

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, office-ui-fabric-react

Has anyone got known a technique/trick for overriding css style of the Office UI Fabric's component
related to Spfx 1.4.0 (for the SP2019)?

More specifically  I would like to update TextField red color border, when the validation fails. Update it to the color as in the default case - that correspond to the Peoplepicker style from the @pnp/spfx-controls-react. (The nice to have also would be to add the exclamation icon as before the validation error text.)

[image: current state of the TextField]

[image: Peoplepicker style from the @pnp/spfx-controls-react.]

TextField parts from the browser developer tools:

[image: developer tools - elements]

[image: developer tools - css,]

TIA,
Mojmir.

Answer (score 1):

I saved the validation result in state.

```
public componentDidUpdate() {

    if(this.state.result){
      $("#TextField10").closest("div").css("border-color","yellow");
    }else{
      $("#TextField10").closest("div").css("border-color","blue");
    }
  }
```

Test result:
[image]

Tip:change the id to your element id

Comment: Hi Amos_MSFT, that seems to be a nice quick workaround runtime solution - thanks for that.

Comment: Hovewer I wonder, whether there is a declarative  solution - how to generally rewrite component css / or styles for UI Fabric egeneral concept like validation,...  I believe, there exist such a possiblity to extend styles by definition... (The following artice https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/wiki/Component-Styling tells about styling of newer version of newly called Fluent UI, but it seems to me too advanced to understand it now and it in hig h probability does not suit to the Office UI Fabric React ver. 5.21 (which is related to the Spfx 1.4.x ))